# Change form contents dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a website and i want it's form to change content dynamically according to the options selected. For example if there is two radio buttons to choose between human and animal, if a user chooses animal, directly the rest of the form will be having the input field for animal age, but if a user chooses human, the rest of theform will be having a select options between female or male sex.

Markup:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="type">Animal
    <input type="radio" name="type">Human
</form>
```

If he selects Animal:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="type">Animal
    <input type="radio" name="type">Human

    <input type="text" name="age_of_animal">
</form>
```

If he selects Human:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="type">Animal
    <input type="radio" name="type">Human

    <select>
        <option>Sex</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>Male</option>
    </select>
```

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? use `.change()` to see if the radio buttons status was changed and then read the `val()` of the radio button that is selected. then use and `if` statement to `show()` or `hide()` the respective sections.  this solution utilizes `classes` to help jquery with selection of specific elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        var radio = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        if (radio == 'animal') {
            $('.animalAge').show();
            $('.gender').hide();
        }
        else if (radio == 'human') {
            $('.animalAge').hide();
            $('.gender').show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="animal"/>Animal
<input type="radio" name="type" value="human"/>Human
<br/><br/>
<input class="animalAge" type="text" name="age_of_animal" style="display:none;"/>
<select class="gender" style="display:none;">
    <option>Sex</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good logic. Worked perfectly.